# C++: random number generation using Stroustrup example?

Tags: c++

I'm using the random number generation from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 129.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to be random and keeps generating and int 1.  Does anyone know why it's not generating a random number 1-6?

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using my_engine = default_random_engine;
    using my_distribution = uniform_int_distribution<>;

    my_engine re {};
    my_distribution one_to_six {1,6};
    auto die = bind(one_to_six,re);

    int x = die();

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}


g++ -pedantic -lpthread test92.cc && ./a.out
1
```

Comment: You need to seed the engine.

Comment: It seems like you need to read your book more carefully. I'm sure Stroustrup mentioned that this will be deterministic unless you seed it. Also know that MinGW's `std::random_device` is deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to seed your engine (`re`) with some random:
Replace:

```
my_engine re {};
```

With:

```
std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
my_engine re(rd());
```